# Java base64 encoding output from Apache Common the "wrong" result

Tags: java, base64

I am trying to use the Base64 encoding functionality from Apache Common. But I seem to get the "wrong" result. The doc is [here](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html).

My code is like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
String data = "hi,all,how can this happen?";

byte[] databytes = Base64.encodeBase64(data.getBytes());
data = databytes.toString();

System.out.println(data);
//the result is:
//[B@121cc40
```

However I encode the same string using Python, the code is:

```
import base64
print base64.b64encode("hi,all,how can this happen?")
#The result is aGksYWxsLGhvdyBjYW4gdGhpcyBoYXBwZW4/
```

How can there be such difference?

Comment: Its printing the reference to it, not the encoding.

Comment: Didn't you recognize `@` is not a valid Base64 char? You're calling the `toString()` of the `byte[]` object.

Comment: use new String(data);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how you print a byte (or any other type of) array in Java, if you want to view its contents.
[**This is**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
```

Comment: Thanks, it changes a bit. But why do I see an array of integers after printing it. How can I convert it to a string?

Comment: Read the JavaDoc. It describes the format of the string that `Arrays.toString(byte[])` returns. There are plenty of other question on SO which tell you how to get a base64 string in Java; I suggest you search and read.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

    public class Codec {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          String data = "hi,all,how can this happen?";
          String encodedText;

          // Base64
          encodedText = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(data.getBytes()));
          System.out.println("Encoded: " + encodedText);
          System.out.println("Decoded:" 
              + new String(Base64.decodeBase64(encodedText.getBytes())));

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
```

Now it will encode your String data

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the address. 
If you want to print the String data, you can use,

```
String password = new String(databytes);
System.out.println("Encoded String "+ password)
```